# Delete query in SparkSteaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm in the middle of a SparkStreaming project and I find myself doing many writeStreams with query names. Attached is an example:

```
    .format("memory") \
    .queryName("infoGames") \
    .outputMode("complete") \
    .start()
```

It's beautiful and pretty but at the end it annoys me... Impossible to restart again because the queryname exists.

I would therefore like to be able to DELETE the queryname that I created in order to be able to writeStream again and avoid doing a Sparksession.stop()

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance for your feedback !